# How to find a matching value from userdefaults keys

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, dictionary, nsuserdefaults

I'm still new with Swift so I'll try to explain this as best as I can...

I have a plist that is a dictionary array. Here's a portion of it:

[image: Image of plist]

So with the below code, I want to only add the information in the data variable only if the title key matches a userdefaults key. So if the value of the "title" key matches a similar key in my userdefaults, then add it into data (which is then used to populate my tableview). I've been trying to figure this out ALL day with no success so please help.

```
if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "categories", withExtension: "plist"),
        let contents = NSArray(contentsOf: url)!.sortedArray(using: [NSSortDescriptor(key: "tag", ascending: true)]) as? [[String:String]]
{
    data = contents
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `NSArray(contentsOf` in Swift at all. There are `PropertyListSerialization` and `PropertyListDecoder`. And to avoid the extra step to sort the data save the property list accordingly sorted.

Create a struct

```
struct Item {
   let favorite, tag, title, text : String
}
```

And load and filter the data if the value in `UserDefaults` is not `nil`

```
let savedTitle = UserDefaults.shared.string(forKey: "title")

let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "categories", withExtension: "plist")!
do {
   let data = try Data(contentOf: url)
   let contents = try PropertyListDecoder().decode([Item].self, from: data)
   let filteredItems = savedTitle == nil ? contents : contents.filter{$0.title == savedTitle!}
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```